# Scroll SearchView to the top - searchView is in the middle of fragment

Tags: android, scrollview, searchview

I have a searchView in the middle of fragment. When I tap on it, it expand a keyboard which cover list (which is under the searchView) and place for writing queries (searchView). Is there any possibility to somehow scroll to the top whole layout when tap on search icon? Currently I set all the views above searchView to `myViews.visibility = View.GONE` and I've received proper behaviour but I am not sure if this is correct - especially since above searchView I have a map. What's your opinion?

Greetings

Comment: in manifest file add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in your activity

Comment: But why add this? AdjustingPan will not scroll searchView to the top but only lay in my current view

Comment: please share your screenshot after adding the adjustpan in manifest

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `searchComponent` is a direct child of the root layout. You can simply use `objectAnimator` over translation y to move it to the top of the screen.

```
var originalY = searchComponent.y // its the starting position of searchComponent which can be used to bring it back to the initial position 
val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(searchComponent, "translationY", originalY, 0)
animator.duration = 500
animator.start()
```

`searchComponent` - is composed of the `recyclerView` and the `searchView` itself

`0` is the final position of y